# Comparing an array of users to an array of structs with user object as attribute, and returning matches in another array of structs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, struct, matching

I have an array of users who are friends. Let us call this array:

```
friends
```

I then have an array of structs. Each struct has a user object as an attribute (it also has a rank attribute).  Here's what the struct class looks like, to add some context:

```
class Leader < Struct.new(:rank, :user); end
```

Let us call this array of structs:

```
all_leaders_plus_rank
```

I want to compare **friends** and **all_leaders_plus_rank**, and add the match from **all_leaders_plus_rank** to a new array of structs called **friendly_leaders**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
friendly_leaders = all_leaders_plus_rank.select do |lpr|
  friends.include?(lpr.user)
end
```